# Timeout for function

Tags: java

How can I make such thing possible in java ? Or to be more presice I would like to make timeout for my function.

Pseudo code:

```
public String aLotOfWork()
{
    return hardWork(); 

    if(hardWork() is still executing after 30 seconds)
           return "TimeOut";


}
```

I can use TimerTask for this but I cannot return any value from timer task run() to my upper function

```
TimerTask task = new TimerTask() {
    public void run() 
    {
        return ""; // timerTask run must be void.
    }
};
Timer timer = new Timer();
timer.schedule(task, 50000, 1);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Checkout the [FutureTask](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/FutureTask.html) class. It provides a method called `get(timeout, timeUnit)`. Off load the `hardwork` task to the `FutureTask` Class

```
public String aLotOfWork() {

  FutureTask task = new FutureTask<String>(new Callable<String>() {

    public String call() {
       return hardwork();
    }
  });

  try {
     return task.get(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
  } catch(TimeoutException e) {
     return "Timeout";
  }
  catch(Exception e) {
     return "Timeout"; // or whatever you like
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
void method() {
    long endTimeMillis = System.currentTimeMillis() + 10000;
    while (true) {
        // method logic
        if (System.currentTimeMillis() > endTimeMillis) {
            // do some clean-up
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This will put heavy load on the CPU.